# Rendering Flask HTML forms results in "UnboundLocalError"

Tags: python, flask

I want to make a Flask application that receives the details from a user. After a successful registration, a new page will be displayed showing the entered details.

The application is built using [HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) and not by using [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

**Here is the code for app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/register',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def user():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form
        name =  result['name']
        phoneno = result['phoneno']
        email = result['email']
        password = result['password']
        if name or phoneno or email or password is not None:
            print name,phoneno,email,password
    return render_template("register.html",result=result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**This is the HTML page of register.html:**

```
<html>
  <body>

  <form action = "/success" method = "POST">
     <p>Name <input type = "text" name = "name" /></p>
     <p>Phone no <input type = "text" name = "phoneno" /></p>
     <p>Email <input type = "text" name = "email" /></p>
     <p>Password <input type ="text" name = "password" /></p>
     <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
  </form>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

What I am getting now is this error:

```
Full Traceback
**UnboundLocalError**
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment. 

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000,       in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
  response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/protocol/PycharmProjects/tut/app.py", line 17, in user
  return render_template("register.html",result=result)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

I tried to print the values, but nothing is shown in the console, so I couldn't rectify this error.

Comment: That leads me to believe that your indentation here doesn't match the indentation in your actual file.

Comment: what's the form's content type?

Comment: @dim Can you please check the app.py once more?

Comment: @roy I dont get what you meant by content here

Comment: Content type is not added to the form. Is it necessary to add the content type?

Comment: Sorry not content type but the fom enctype is anyone else getting a _ValueError_ ?

Comment: Hold on...I see `action = "/success"` in your HTML form and in your view function `user()`, you attached it to the route `/register` ???..

Comment: And..are u sure that the `return` statement is indented the same way in your post here...may be in your original code it is outside `if` block ?

Comment: Where is the html file on which you render the result? You need another html page to display the result, it can't render on register.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` only exists if the `request` method is `POST`, so if the request method was `GET`(which is the default request one), that is when the page is requested before submitting user data form, then `result` won't be existing, hence the error message. Plus, you need to render the `result` object into another template, for example `user.html`:

```
@app.route('/register',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def user():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form
        name =  result['name']
        phoneno = result['phoneno']
        email = result['email']
        password = result['password']
        if name or phoneno or email or password is not None:
            print name,phoneno,email,password
            return render_template("user.html",result=result)
    return render_template("register.html")
```

Another thing, if the above view function is for `register.html` form, then you also need to change in `form` block, from:

```
<form action = "/success" method = "POST">
```

to

```
<form action = "/register" method = "POST">
```

Comment: @roy Thank you for the support :)

Comment: @Protocol...sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('register.html')


@app.route('/success',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def user():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        results = request.form
    return render_template('new.html',results=results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

new.html

```
{% for k,v in results.iteritems() %}
    <p>{{v}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

register.html is the same as yours.
You are missing a html template to display your form input data, new.html file will render the values you enter in your form.