# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'participant' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables, flask

```
@app.route('/list', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def list():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        participant = Participant.query.all()
    return render_template('admin/list.html', participant=participant)
```

Comment: think about what happens `if request.method != "POST"`?

Comment: yes it works thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering Flask HTML forms results in "UnboundLocalError"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675377/rendering-flask-html-forms-results-in-unboundlocalerror)

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious really

```
@app.route('/list', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def list():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        participant=Participant.query.all()
    return render_template('admin/list.html', participant=participant)
```

the scope of your variable is the issue, you can get over this by simply ensuring your `return` statement sits within your `list()` function. Besides, ensure to avoid using python reserved for naming functions or variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are fetching any value then you need to handle it with request or you can initialise participant before performing query on it. This error is because you haven't initialised participant before and referring it for query.
@app.route('/list', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def list():
 
 if request.method == 'POST':
    participant=request.args.get('participant')

    participant=Participant.query.all()
   
return render_template('admin/list.html', participant=participant)
```